# how to show records that share the same date excluding hour and minutes and also comparing the table with itself

Tags: sql

in the following table I'm trying to compare it to itself by using self join to be able to retrieve the records that share the same RegCode and different AdmissionID and having the same AdmitDate excluding the hours and minutes,

```
 AdmitDate      AdmissionID RegCode          FirsName
6/16/2015 11:15   1370       JB01.000000001  Eric
6/16/2015 15:24   1393       JB01.000000001  Eric
6/16/2015 18:17   1400       JB01.000000001  Eric
6/17/2015 10:55   1445       JB01.000008751  Sara
7/15/2015 15:51   2726       JB01.000000879  ellen
7/20/2015 10:30   2781       JB01.00000147   maison 
8/18/2015 15:07   4143       JB01.00000879   jeffery
12/23/2015 10:15  12341      JB01.00000850   jordan
5/31/2016 13:28   25406      JB01.00000545   leen
2/16/2017 9:49    45999      JB01.00000548   joseph
```

for example it should retrieve Eric because he has more than one record with the same AdmitDate (ignoring hours and minutes) and RegCode but different AdmissionID

```
AdmitDate        AdmissionID    RegCode         FirstName
6/16/2015 11:15    1370       JB01.000000001    Eric
6/16/2015 15:24    1393       JB01.000000001    Eric
6/16/2015 18:17    1400       JB01.000000001    Eric
```

so basically I'm trying to retrieve the records that has more than one AdmissionID with the same date for the same RegCode,
I've faced the issue with the AdmitDate Because it also capture Hour and minute , and when using an alias for a subquery that seprated the AdmitDate using Datepart I'm unable to use the alias name in the select and group by ,

i hope i expalined it briefly since I'm not that experinced with SQL your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQL Server:

```
select *, 
count(AdmissionID) over(partitionBy AdmitDateDate, RegCode, FirstName) as [count]
from 
   (select *, cast(AdmitDate as Date) [AdmitDateDate] from <yourTable>) o
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL Server

```
SELECT  DISTINCT p.* 
FROM    <yourtable> AS p
    INNER JOIN <yourtable> AS c ON c.RegCode = p.RegCode AND c.AdmissionID <> p.AdmissionID AND CAST(c.AdmitDate AS date) = CAST(p.AdmitDate AS date)
```

Result

```
AdmitDate                AdmissionID   RegCode          FirstName
---------------------------------------------------------------
2015-06-16 11:15:00.000  1370          JB01.000000001   Eric
2015-06-16 15:24:00.000  1393          JB01.000000001   Eric
2015-06-16 18:17:00.000  1400          JB01.000000001   Eric
```